# Resample using Rasterio with Resampling.sum method

Tags: python, rasterio, resampling

I want to resample Geotiff image using Rasterio with Resampling.sum

I have the following code, however, it returns,

> ResamplingAlgorithmError: <Resampling.sum: 13> can be used for warp
> operations but not for reads and writes

How do I solve this problem?

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.enums import Resampling
scale_factor = 10

# Open the input GeoTIFF file
with rasterio.open('input.tif') as src:
    # Resample using the Sum method
    data = src.read(
        out_shape=(
            src.count,
            int(src.height * scale_factor),
            int(src.width * scale_factor)
        ),
        resampling=Resampling.sum
    )

    # Update the transform to reflect the new resolution
    transform = src.transform * src.transform.scale(
        (src.width / data.shape[-1]),
        (src.height / data.shape[-2])
    )

    # Write the resampled data to a new GeoTIFF file
    with rasterio.open('output.tif', 'w', 
                       driver='GTiff', 
                       width=data.shape[2], 
                       height=data.shape[1], 
                       count=src.count, 
                       dtype=data.dtype, 
                       crs=src.crs, 
                       transform=transform) as dst:
        dst.write(data)
```

Comment: Read the original data into an array 1st and then use the reproject method to do the sum resampling: https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/reproject.html